# basic studies on declaratives in speech act theory

Tags: pragmatics, speech-acts

I am looking for some sources on declaratives in speech act theory. I have basic studies like Austin, Searle or Bach & Harnish. What  I'm looking for is more specific books or articles on basic or specific properties of declaratives. Can I have any help from you guys?

Comment: There's a nice [article on _Assertion_](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/assertion/) in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy that has a good bibliography at the end.